# Nuget does not restore packages from source control

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

We are migrating all our projects to use nuget references.
Together with a source control (in our case DevOps and Git) I noticed a strange behavior of the nuget package manager.

When we check in projects with nuget references, other coworkers (who checkout this project) get reference errors within the project.
I analysed it an noticed that, in the working version of the branch, the dlls of the nugetpackages are not included. The package.config looks fine to me.

> My question to this is: do we need to checkin packages dlls from
>   nuget to the source control? In my understanding nuget should check if
>   the packages/assemblies are downloaded and if not, should re-download
>   them.

In visualstudio under nuget package manager -> "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" both options are checked (on all clients).

I also checked in a project only with the packages.config - without the packages folder. 
But the references are not recoginised as before / an autorestore did not happen on the load / build of the project.

Comment: Hi Twiebie, do you use something like Devops or what, this issue seems not to be something about local VS only. Maybe you can add some tag to make it more clear.

Comment: Hei @LanceLi-MSFT - yes we use DevOps and Git. But I think the problem is directed to nuget. 
When users checkout from the repo, nuget does not download the binaries for packages, which leads to missing references for all users.

Comment: Do you mean if you download a project from github repo, when building it the package restore not works which causes the build errors. If so, please try right-click solution=>restore nuget packages and check the output, please share the error messgae if it exists. Also you can try if rebuild the solution makes any help.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I mean. When I click "Restore Nuget Packages" it says "everything is installed - nothing to restore" but my references zu the nuget packages still stay in "waring". 
When I have a look to the fileexplorer - the packages folder is there ( it is checked in) but the dll's are missing, because you don't want to checkin binaries to the version control. 

So in short - the restore does not restore missing dlls or package folders.

Comment: What vs version do you use? And if the project you download from github is open-source, please share the link here so that I can check it directly.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT we use a devops repo for our private projects. 
We have tried it with VS 15, 17 and 19. 
All have the same behavior to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my erros my switching from packages.config to packagereferences. In the build / rebuild event all DLLs are now pulled from nuget sources, if they are not existing.

See this blogpost for reference https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to include the dlls for the packages in source control. The packages.config is all you need as this contains enough information to fetch all of the required libraries that are required to run your code.

In Devops you need to add a [nuget restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to your build. This will pull down all of the required dlls.

Using a package manager like nuget (or npm etc) allows you to keep only your code in source control. It also prevents cases of "it works on my machine" where Developer1 has a specific locally referenced dll but Developer2 doesn't.

If reference errors are occurring for individual developers it could be that someone has checked in a reference to a local file rather than a nuget package.

Comment: The problem is not a buildjob or so. It is when other developers checkout their code. Because nuget does not restore the packages. So I think a nuget task would be "a next step". I checked all nuget.configs (in projects they were not existing) but the global ones. nuget.org was not excludet so I don't get it, why nuget does not autorestore the packages.